# Onelogin Weird Error

Tags: authentication, onelogin

I experienced an odd bug during password generation, during account creation.  The bug doesn't let me continue when I press save.  So, naturally, I cleared my cache and retried.

Now, going to my created subdomain, it leads me to the account log on page. Since, the initial password have not been created, I would naturally select "Forget Password" However, the site does not allow me to request for a new password, as both Email and SMS options do not work (no response received). I also have tried a lot of ways to communicate, but it redirects me back to my account log on page (which like I've said, I can't go in my account).

Sorry if this is the wrong channel/medium.

Comment: Mods, feel free to close this question if this violates anything.

Comment: Try reaching out to OneLogin support. This is more a general support issue than a developer thing.